# Terminal, Prompt changed to "-Bash-4.2" and colors lost

Tags: bash, terminal, gnome-terminal, bashrc

Usually my terminal prompt was

```
username place$
```

now it only shows

```
bash-4.2$
```

and all the color settings have been lost (on the terminal profile I have the same color scheme, but it just don't show colors)

I don't have any idea of what happens (and I don't know how to search for this).

It changes from nothing, I was working with eclipse and maven, opened a new terminal and the new terminal didn't have colors.

Note: I don't have a ~/.bashrc file, but I have a ~/.bash_profile.

Comment: The prompt is set by the variable PS1, [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt) you can read more about this, there is also various examples of colored prompts

Comment: Does this happen 1) Only when you log in on a console, 2) Only when you open a new GUI terminal, 3) Both 1 and 2?  If you are not sure about #1, switch to a VT and log in, or try `bash -l`.

Comment: @TAFKA'goldilocks' both, if i use bash -l the colours come back, but the promp stills at "bash-4.2$"

Comment: If my answer doesn't work, post the output from `echo $PS1` in the login version w/ the colors.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/236005/5132 .

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The prompt variable `$PS1` was probably not set, so the built-in default `\s-\v\$` is used.

When bash starts up interactively, it sources a configuration file, usually either `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`, presuming they exist, and this is how a fancier prompt is set.  From `man bash`:

> **INVOCATION**
>
> [...] 
>   When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a
>   non-interactive shell  with  the  --login
>          option,  it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.  After
>          reading that file, it looks for *~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login,* and 
>   *~/.profile,* in  that  order [...]
>
> [...] When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash reads and executes commands from
>          *~/.bashrc,* if that file exists.

Not having your prompt set can occur in two different contexts then, login shells and non-login shells.  If you use a display manager to log directly into the GUI, you don't encounter login shells unless you switch to a virtual console (via, e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd> + F1 to F6).  However, you can test your bash login profile in the GUI by opening a new login shell explicitly: `bash -l`.

## Problem occurs with non-login shells

If the problem occurs with, e.g., normal GUI terminals, then either your `~/.bashrc` is missing, or it has been edited to exclude sourcing a global file, probably `/etc/bashrc`.

- If `~/.bashrc` does not exist, there should be a `/etc/skel/.bashrc` used to create it for new users.  Simply copy that file into your home directory, and your default prompt should come back for the next new shell you open.
- If `~/.bashrc` does exist, check to see if there is a line somewhere that sources `/etc/bashrc`:

  ```
  . /etc/bashrc
    -OR-
  source /etc/bashrc
  ```

  If not, check if that file exists (it should, at least on most linux distros) and add such a line to your `~/.bashrc`.

## Problem occurs with login shells

If the problem occurs with login shells as well as non-login shells, the problem is probably the same as above.  If it occurs *only* with login shells, you either don't have one of the files mentioned for login shells under the INVOCATION quote above, or they don't source your `~/.bashrc`, which is normal on most linux distros.  If none of those files exists, create `~/.bash_profile` with this in it:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
  . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

This allows you, for the most part, to keep your configuration in one file (`~/.bashrc`).

---

If no matter what you do you cannot get a prompt back, you can create one and put it into `~/.bashrc` this way:

```
if [ "$PS1 ]; then
    PS1= .... # see below
fi
```

This is because $PS1 is set and has a default value for interactive shells, and you don't want to set it otherwise since other things may use this value to determine whether this is an interactive environment.

The bash man page contains a section PROMPTING which describes how to set a prompt with dynamic features such as your user name and current working directory, which would be, e.g.,:

```
PS1="\u \w:"
```

There's a guide to [using color here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124407/what-are-the-color-codes-that-i-can-use-in-my-ps1-prompt/124409#124409).  Pay attention to the fact that you should enclose non-printed characters in `\[` and `\]` (there's a discussion of this at the end of the answer about colors).

Comment: Thanks TAFKA!, most than just an answer I learned something new :)!

Answer (score 3):

Just paste this in ~/.bashrc and ~/.bash_profile as root on effected user.

`# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi`

Answer (score 0):

Had to upgrade Cygwin bash for security reasons.

the old bash = 4.1.10(4)-release (i686-pc-cygwin)  circa 2009

```
$ echo $PS1

\[\e]0;\w\a\]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\n\$
```

the new bash = 4.4.12(3)-release (i686-pc-cygwin)  circa 2016

To get the exact same look and feel had to add to `.bashrc`:

```
#

GREEN="\[$(tput setaf 2)\]"

YELLOW="\[$(tput setaf 3)\]"

RESET="\[$(tput sgr0)\]"

PS1="\n${GREEN}\u@\h ${YELLOW}\w${RESET}\n$ "

cd $HOME

#
```

note: including the `cd $HOME`

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem when our DBA was trying to create an oracle user for DB installation. Instead of changing entries, he deleted some profile required files for the user.

I resolved by copying following default files from other user who wasn't facing issue:

1. `/home/username/.bashrc`
2. `/home/username/.bashrc_profile`
3. `/home/username/.bashrc_logout`
4. `/home/username/.bashrc_history`

No need to change any settings/text in these files.

Log out the session and login back. You should have your default shell (bash usually) restored with colors and login prompt.