# Ubuntu shell does not show the current path

Tags: bash, ubuntu

In my Ubuntu 12.04, the prompt always show the following only (no matter what path I'm in):

```
-bash-4.2#
```

I guessed it is because `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` is configured incorrectly.

My `.bashrc` is as follow:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "$debian_chroot" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

and my .`bash_profile` is as follow:

```
JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/javac | sed "s:/bin/javac::")
```

How do I restore the default settings (to show the current directory) in my shell?

---

**UPDATE:** Here is the output of `bash -x`:

http://pastebin.com/HT4xncGw (way too long to paste here)

Comment: You need to change `PS1` variable.

Comment: As I can see there is a **root** terminal…

Comment: How do you run bash? Run `bash -x` inside the first one and post the full output.

Comment: added the output of `bash -x` in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normally specified in the file `/etc/bash.bashrc` on Ubuntu systems. The environment variable `$PS1` sets the values of the shell prompt. This is Ubuntu's default prompt:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

Copy that line in your `/etc/bash.bashrc` (maybe it is already there, but commented). However, after that, open a new `bash` process and your prompt should be set again.

Comment: the exact line is in the `/etc/bash.bashrc` uncommented, and it's not overwritten by the lines after that...

Comment: What's the output of `echo $PS1` in that terminal?

Comment: The output is `\s-\v\$` , don't know where it is overwritten...

Comment: Search for it: `grep -r "PS1" ~ /etc/`. It must be somewhere in the homedirectory or in `/etc`

Comment: you won't believe that, the `\s-\v\$` does not appear in the search result of `grep -Ir "PS1" ~ /etc/` ( I filtered away the binary results )

Comment: Ok, then the file is maybe not loaded. Can you add a line for example `echo "blah"` in /etc/bash.bashrc and then start another terminal. So you can the sure the file is processed when that line appears.

Comment: Right, the echo line doesn't get called in a new session of terminal

Comment: Is that bash invoked as `sh` if yes, the bash.bashrc file is not read, check `/etc/passwd`, also check the permission `ls -l /etc/bash.bashrc`

Comment: permission is : `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root` and seems `sh` linked to `dash` : `lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       4 Mar 30  2012 sh -> dash`

Comment: Have you placed `echo blah` as **first** line after the initial comments in /etc/bash.bashrc, not as last line?

Comment: moving to the 1st line, the result remains the same.

Comment: How do you call that new bash process? Whats the user you have logged in? What happend when calling bash in the termian, just: `bash` or `bash --rcfile /etc/bash.bashrc`?

Comment: I use SSH to connect to the Ubuntu. For new process, I logout from server & re-login via SSH. When I issue `bash`, it works like what I want to achieve, and the echo line appears.

Comment: And you login with root? Can you post eh first line of `etc/passwd`? `sed -n '1p' /etc/passwd`

Comment: I login with `root` ( I know this is not a good practice... but this server is configured with this ). First line is : `root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash`

Comment: Have you tried to ssh from another host/with another ssh client (putty for example)? I think it's the local ssh client configuration that gives parameters or environment variables to the remote bash, preventing it from starting normally