# bash prompt got reset every time I login

Tags: bash, prompt

I asked [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/236005/27309) some time ago about the shell does not displaying the path. Recently I found out that the `.bashrc` does not get sourced (and this should be a [normal practice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161249/bashrc-not-executed-when-opening-new-terminal)?). Currently, the shell command prompt is like this:

```
-bash-4.3#
```

after I executed `source .bashrc`, I am able to obtain my expected shell command prompt:

```
root@ubuntu2011:~#
```

where `ubuntu2011` is the machine name. How can I make the prompt looks like the latter one every time I login?

p.s. the `.bashrc` is from: `cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc`

---

**UPDATE**: the contents of `~/.profile` is as follow:

```
# ~/.profile: executed by Bourne-compatible login shells.

if [ "$BASH" ]; then
  if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
  fi
fi

mesg n
```

and `echo $BASH` returns `/bin/bash`

---

**UPDATE**: Answers of @terdon's questions:

1. How do I login to server?

> I use `ssh root@111.222.333.444` to login as `root`

2. Are those command executed as root?

> Yes.

---

**UPDATE**: The output of `ls -l ~/.{profile,bashrc,bash_profile,bash_login}`:

```
ls: cannot access /root/.bash_login: No such file or directory
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   63 Dec 24  2012 /root/.bash_profile
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3637 May 17 17:00 /root/.bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  140 Apr 23  2010 /root/.profile
```

Comment: open `~/.profile`, write `. /home/me/.bashrc`

Comment: @123 is it a normal practice to do so? I have several Ubuntu servers, but none requires me to do so .

Comment: Normally `./profile` sources `/etc/profile`, which sources `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `$HOME/.bashrc` but evidently something is not working on your server. You can just skip all that though and use you local `.bashrc` and `.profile`.

Comment: IS that the entire contents of `.profile` ?

Comment: @123 not quite: `~/.profile` does not source `/etc/profile` and `/etc/profile` does not source `~/.bashrc`. *Bash* itself will read some of these files depending on how it's being run. See `man bash` or [Difference between Login Shell and Non-Login Shell?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46856) or [Difference between .bashrc and .bash\_profile](http://superuser.com/a/183980) or [Scripts in /etc/profile.d Being Ignored?](http://askubuntu.com/a/438170).

Comment: @terdon On sles it is definitely set up that way by default.  I understand how the individual files are used regarding login/non-login. `test -z "$PROFILEREAD" && . /etc/profile || true` is the first line of my default setup of `./profile`

Comment: @123 this is the entire `.profile` contents.

Comment: @terdon `~/.profile
sets LANG variable, sources /etc/profile, iF it has not already been run (checks PROFILEREAD variable), sources ~/.bashrc, runs the fortune program if you uncomment it.` from suse documentation. Maybe, dunno, don't think I'm "completely" wrong though.

Comment: @Raptor `after i executed source .bashrc`, given that this doesn't have the `~/`, just to clarify you are sourcing the same bashrc, not some random one in your PATH ?

Comment: @123 no, apparently not for SLES (I removed the *completely wrong*) from my previous comment. Now I'm really curious as to why in the world they would do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because you are logging in through `ssh`. It comes down to the differences between login and non-login shells. When you connect via ssh, you run a login interactive shell. As explained in `man bash`, this sort of shell will:

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a  non-inter‐
>          active  shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes com‐
>          mands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.   After  reading
>          that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile,
>          in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one  that
>          exists  and  is  readable.  The --noprofile option may be used when the
>          shell is started to inhibit this behavior.

In other words, `~/.bashrc` is ignored by default when running login shells. The simple solution is to explicitly source it from one of the files that are read. As you can see above, login shells will first try to read `~/.bash_profile`, and if that doesn't exist `~/.bash_login`, and if that also doesn't exist, they read `~/.profile`. Since you have a `~/.bash_profile` file, you will need to add these lines to it:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your ~/.profile

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

Comment: it's already in the `.profile`. I've updated the question to show the contents of the `.profile`

Comment: @Raptor you really need to tell us how you are logging in to the machine. That's what makes the difference.