# How to get colored output with tail command

Tags: linux, colors, tail

Below is the tail statement:

```
tail -4 FDECMP1_$$.log
```

I need to print the last 4 lines of file `FDECMP1_$$.log` in Red.

Answer (score 2):

This command will do the job:

```
printf "%s" $(printf '\033[0;31m');tail -4 FDECMP1_$$.log
```

Comment: Maybe you need to reset the colour after the `tail` command, though.

Answer (score 0):

As @galoget showed, you can use the [ANSI escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) to change the coloring of shell texts.

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/124409/47505) has more information on this and a nice xterm-256-color-chart to conveniently find the correct color for your purposes.

Comment: Why answer the question again when it is already answered? In these cases, please add a comment to the existing answer, instead.