# Print exit status code after each command in terminal

Tags: terminal, zsh, exit-status

I would like to print at every lauched command in zsh exit code value.
E.g.

```
$ cat file_not_present
cat: file_not_present: No such file or directory
Exit code 1
```

I only know that I can print error code of last command launched in terminal with

```
$ echo $?
```

How can I do?

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/653413

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Personally, I add `%(?..%B(%?%)%b)` to my `$PROMPT`, so that the exit status of the previous command be shown in bold in brackets if it was unsuccessful, which is less intrusive than printing the exit status of every command.

To print the exit status of every *failing* command, you can do:

```
TRAPERR() print -u2 Exit status: $?
```

```
$ false; false; (exit 123)
Exit status: 1
Exit status: 1
Exit status: 123
(123)$
```

(the `(123)$` being from that `$PROMPT` mentioned above).

For every command:

```
TRAPDEBUG() print -u2 Exit status: $?
```

But that will likely get very annoying.

You can also print the exit status of the last command that was run with:

```
print_last_status() print -u2 Exit status: $?
precmd_functions+=(print_last_status)
```

```
$ false; (exit 123); true
Exit status: 0
```

Like for the `$PROMPT` approach, you only see the status of the last command run in the command line you sent at the previous prompt.

In any case, printing it on stderr (as I do above with `-u2`) will likely cause fewer problems than doing it on stdout. Doing `print Exit status: $? > /dev/tty` may be even better.

Comment: I find my own way of printing bold exit code:
```TRAPERR() print -u2 "Exit status: ${bold}$?${normal}"```
I set bold and normal bash variable as follow
```bold=$(tput bold); normal=$(tput sgr0)```

Comment: @lecciovich95, use `print -Pu2 "Exit status: %B%?%b"` instead. `zsh` also has a builtin version of `tput`: `echoti`, as well as `$terminfo[bold]`

Comment: thank you, it works! It's more compact solution :)

Comment: `setopt print_exit_value` is a zsh option to print non-zero exit codes

Comment: Thanks @Wes, I wasn't aware of that option. I'd suggest you write an answer with that.

Answer (score 5):

You can add any user defined function into `precmd_functions`:

```
print_status() echo $?
precmd_functions+=(print_status)
```

It is executed before every prompt, that means after the command.

Answer (score 3):

In zsh, you can use the `precmd` hook and do something like this (taken from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/735969/151431)):

```
% PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "Exit code: %s\n" $?'
% precmd() { eval "$PROMPT_COMMAND" }
% cat file_not_present
cat: file_not_present: No such file or directory
Exit code: 1
```

In bash, you can use the `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable for that:

```
$ PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "Exit code: %s\n" $?'
$ cat file_not_present
cat: file_not_present: No such file or directory
Exit code: 1
```

Comment: Also, doing that ugly `eval "$PROMPT_COMMAND"` would only be for bash users trying to minimise differences when using `zsh`. Doing it the other way round (use `PROMPT_COMMAND=precmd` in `bash` and define `precmd()` for both) would seem cleaner to me.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas sounds reasonable. I don't use zsh myself, I just found that SU answer, checked that it works, and posted.